# Opencart - Show product count next to each manufacturer

Tags: count, opencart, product

I am trying to show the product count next to the manufacturers. I am also trying to hide any manufacture with 0 product count, so only show the manufacture if the product count contains a product. Else hide it.

I have attempted the following below. However, the product count is just showing as (0) on all manufactures. Doesn't get the count properly.

I am using OC 2.0.3.1.

1. Open file `catalog\controller\product\manufacturer.php`
2. Find

   ```
   $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
   ```

   and add below code after that line

   ```
   $this->load->model('catalog/product');
   ```
3. Find

   ```
   'name' => $result['name'],
   ```

   and replace with

   ```
   'name' => $result['name'] . ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(array('filter_manufacturer_id' => $result['manufacturer_id'])) . ')',
   ```

It's not working. Any help would be appreciated.